# Messages are not pushed on the site chatbot using Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, chatbot, google-tag-manager-server-side

I'm facing the next issue. We've successfully implemented a chatbot on our website using Crisp. It works as expected in its basic version. However, we've encountered the need to create more complex scenarios of user conversations. We would like sending messages to users based on data from Google Analytics through the website and chatbot.

That's where my challenge comes in!

In console and Crisp chat within Google Tag Manager Preview Mode also all is okay, I got messages from the tag manager, I can even see my messages in the Crisp admin panel. But on the live website, it's a different story. I'm not even able to see a basic message in the console with basic triggers like Load a page or Page View
 `<script> console.log("This is a test") </script>`

I can't clarify the problem point, bcs I lack knowledge:

1. Are the tag manager scripts not working through the front end of the site?
2. Could there be errors placed in the tag manager code within the head and body of the site?
3. Are there other factors causing this issue?

I'd greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving my problem.